# What does {} mean in C#'

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DataGridView cell that is of type System.Single.

```
if (myDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value == null) 
{
    //some code
}
```

`myDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value` has value `{}`. It's not `null`, nor is it `0`, what should be on the right hand side of `==` to make the conditional true?

Comment: Where do you see it having a value of `{}`? If it's in the debugger, that should show you the data type as well... I suspect it's DbNull, but you can find out more easily than we can.

Comment: `"{}"` or something maybe? I don't fully understand your question honestly. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Have you tried `DBNull.Value`?

Comment: Add a watch for `myDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.GetType().Name`

Comment: Bad title.   { } then you want to know about ==?

Comment: @JonSkeet It is DBNull, as you suspected. I saw it in the tooltip when my cursor hovers over that line of code. The tooltip does not show the data type however. Where do you find out the data type?

Comment: I'd use the Watch window in the debugger.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks so much! The Watch window is something new to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's something called `DBNull.Value` as stated before you can use it:

```
if (myDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value == DBNull.Value) 
{
    //some code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As noted, the value is an instance of `DbNull`.

Given that `DbNull.Value` is a singleton (and thus safe for reference comparisons), two options come to mind:

```
if (myDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value == DBNull.Value)
```

or

```
if (myDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value is DbNull)
```

Personally I quite like that latter - it fits in with the "is null" approach within a database, and it reads well... it makes it clearer that I'm interested in nullity as a sort of property rather than performing an actual equality comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
if (DBNull.Value.Equals(myDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value)) 
{
    //some code
}
```